# Gwoffice 0.97 has a dependency issue and won't install

Tags: 12.10, package-management, 64-bit, dependencies, google

When trying to install the latest version of gwoffice 0.97 I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gwoffice : Depends: libgranite1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check the thread at [eidete: Depends: libgranite1 but it is not installable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/eidete/+bug/1080586), it says you need stuff from elementary-os in your sources.list

```
 # sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the two lines for 12.10

```
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu quantal main
 deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu quantal main
```

or for 12.04 as in my case

```
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu precise main
 deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu precise main
```

# sudo apt-get update

For the public key error

```
 # sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key BF36996C4E1F8A59
 # sudo gpg -a --export BF36996C4E1F8A59 | sudo apt-key add -

 # sudo apt-get update
```

And then further update should work as usual